# Hold a mail from sending to complete some operation

Tags: lotus-notes

I am referring extmail sample from Lotus Notes C API toolkit.
It has an event handler for EM_MAILSENDNOTE with flag EM_REG_BEFORE.

I want to hold a mail from being sent at Client side until some operation completes.  However I am not able to figure out how to do this from C API doc.

I can think of following approaches:

1) Change status of the mail so that further processing on that mail will not be done. (e.g 'Send' shared action code changes 'ActionInProgress' field of NotesDocument to "1024")

2) Change status of mail and move that mail to some other folder

Please suggest how to do this using C API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, I believe this is normally done by changing the value of the RoutingState item to "HOLD".